# Show user his products

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is my first year with HTML, PHP, JAVASCRIPT and mysql!

And i am having a problem, im making a website that users can only see them products.
For example: Admin created a product for MARTA, when MARTA log in she can see her product.

I have created the table USER_EQUIPMENT but i don't know how can i use it like i want.

I made something like this:

```
function getEquipment($name)
{
    $query = "select * from equipments where name = '$name'";
    $this->connect();
    $res = $this->execute($query);
    $this->disconnect();
    return $res;
}
```

and then i called it like:

```
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
        include_once('DataAccess.php');
        $da = new DataAccess();
        $res = $da->getEquipment($name);
```

But i doesn't get the equipment by the name.
Little help please?

Thanks.

Comment: check `var_dump($res)`.

Comment: I made it after the `$res = $da->getEquipment($name);` and it shows me something like this:
`object(mysqli_result)[2]
  public 'current_field' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'type' => null
`

Comment: seems query not returning any records.

Comment: do you get any errors? If you don't know place this `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', -1);` at the top of the php file.

Comment: Yes i do, i got a undefined index: name.

Comment: check the structure of **equipments**  table

Comment: It's ok.
I have name column in there.

Comment: Any ideas for this error?